# How I Update single item in List comes from API using pagination in Flutter using Bloc

Tags: flutter, api, listview, pagination

How I can update single item in list view comes from Pagination APIs with flutter using Bloc

I want just to update single item like Instagram when click on like button.

I need best way.

Why I am saying best way?

I need to update a single item and dont want when update a single item on that all items exists in the list get rendered.

```
class CartBloc extends Bloc<CartEvent, CartState> {
  final GetAllCartUsecase getAllCategoryUsecase;

  static int cartLength = 0;

  int page = 1;
  int pageSize = 1;
  bool isRefresh = false;

  CartBloc({
    required this.getAllCategoryUsecase,
  }) : super(CartInitial()) {
    on<GetAllCartEvent>(getAllCart);
    
  }

  void getAllCart(GetAllCartEvent event, Emitter<CartState> emit) async {
    if (page <= pageSize) {
      if (state is CartIsloadingState) return;
      final currentState = state;
      var oldCarts = <CartModel>[];
      if (currentState is CartLoadedState) {
        oldCarts = currentState.carts;
      }
      emit(CartIsloadingState(oldCarts, isFirstFetch: page == 1 && !isRefresh));
      final reposne = await getAllCategoryUsecase(page);
      emit(reposne
          .fold((failure) => CartError(message: _mapFailureToMsg(failure)),
              (newCart) {
        final cart = (state as CartIsloadingState).oldCart;
        page++;
        pageSize = newCart.myCarts!.lastPage!;
        cart.addAll(newCart.myCarts!.data!);
        cartLength = newCart.myCarts!.data!.length;
        return CartLoadedState(carts: cart);
      }));
    }
  }

  

  String _mapFailureToMsg(Failure failure) {
    switch (failure.runtimeType) {
      case ServerFailure:
        return AppStrings.serverFailure;
      case CacheFailure:
        return AppStrings.cacheFailure;

      default:
        return AppStrings.unexpectedError;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried Refresh all item

Comment: Hi, this question should include more details and clarify the problem. And also not related to laravel with this information.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion you can tackle this using bloc by :

- using the privilege of rebuildWhen functionality
- each CartWidget should listen to changes of CartBloc and decide if it should rebuild or not

here is an example

**cart widget**

```
    class CartWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const CartWidget({Key? key, required this.index}) : super(key: key);
  final int index;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<CartBloc, CartState>(
        buildWhen: (previous, current) =>
            previous.cartData.elemntAt(widget.index) !=
            current.cartData.elemntAt(widget
                .index), // or if your single cart data has an id you can select by id  ,
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Container();
        });
  }
}
```

**Cart Bloc**

```
    void updateElementByIndex(int index) {
  state.cartDta.elementAt(index); // update data here
  emit();
}
```

**Home List view**

```
    class CartWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const CartWidget({Key? key, required this.index}) : super(key: key);
  final int index;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => CartWidget(
              index: index,
            ));
  }
}
```

**Note**
make sure you use [equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) to compare objects